# accelerating convergence of a series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

let be a completely convergent series

$$ A= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n} $$

then i define a new series given by

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_{n} $$

wiht $$ c_{n} = a_{n}+a_{n+1}+a_{n+2}+......+ a_{n+k} $$

for some positive integer 'k'

then will this second series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_{n}$ also converge to A ?

will the convergence be faster by grouping terms ?

Comment: I would have though your second series was $(k+1)A - \left(ka_0+(k-1)a_1+(k-2)a_2+\cdots+2a_{k-2}+a_{k-1}\right)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it doesn't (necessarily) converge to the same sum. For example, if $k = 2$ and $a_n = \frac{1}{2^n}$, then
$$c_n = \frac{1}{2^n} + \frac{1}{2^{n + 1}} = \frac{3}{2}a_n.$$
Hence,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n = \frac{3}{2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n = \frac{3}{2} \neq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n.$$
However, I'm thinking you might mean
$$c_n = c_{nk} + c_{nk + 1} + \ldots + c_{nk + n - 1}.$$
This will technically accelerate the series, but not in any significant way or useful way. Of course, computing the terms of the $c_n$ series (without some individual insight into $a_n$) takes $k$ times longer than computing the $a_n$ terms.

Also the acceleration won't change the asymptotic rate of convergence at all (e.g. quadratic convergence will remain quadratic convergence).